# error MIDL2003: redefinition when compiling ATL generated idl with windows.h and sql.h included

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, com, odbc

As part of a requirement, I had to include `sql.h` and `windows.h` in an ATL generated idl.
Unfortunately, it keeps on complaining when  `sql.h` is included

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\sqltypes.h(125): error MIDL2003: redefinition : SQLSCHAR
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\sqltypes.h(131): error MIDL2003: redefinition : SQLUINTEGER
```

And when `windows.h` is included it complains

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(347): error MIDL2003: redefinition : INT
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(832): error MIDL2003: redefinition : Int64ShllMod32
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(832): error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting ; near "{"
```

**Note** I am creating a COM wrapper over ODBC because of which I need to include these files in my generated idl

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this is to define `RC_INVOKED` before the header files are included. This will skip the `typedef`'s and `#define`'s which conflict with declarations in MS IDL files.

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

#define RC_INVOKED 1
#include "windows.h"
#include "sql.h"
```